# jinja2 nested variables

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2

I am currently learning jinja2 and i am unsure on how to address variables the correct way:

Here are my variables in yaml:

```
---
hosts:
   app201.acme.com: {eth0: {ip: 46.0.0.1, netmask: 255.255.255.255}}
   graphite.acme.com: {eth0: {ip: 46.0.0.2, netmask: 255.255.255.255},
                       eth0.1: {ip: 10.2.90.1, netmask: 255.255.255.255}}
```

and here the jinja2 template:

```
{{ fqdn }}
{% for interface in hosts[fqdn] %}
    {{ interface }}
    {{ hosts[fqdn].interface.ip }} << doesn't work
    {{ hosts[fqdn].{{ interface }}.ip }} << doesn't work
    {{ interface.ip }} << doesn't work
{% endfor %}
```

so currently my output looks like this since I can't access second dimension of yaml hash.

graphite.acme.com
eth0.1

eth0

Answer (score 21):

The variable `hosts` is a `dict`. The correct way to access values in `dict` is to use `[]` operator.

```
{{ fqdn }}
{% for interface in hosts[fqdn] %}
    {{ interface }}
    {{ hosts[fqdn][interface]['ip'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

`.` operator is used to access attribute of an object.

Comment: @user1436955, most welcome. You can mark it as an answer if you think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Interestingly interface['ip'] doesn't seem to work, I guess since interface is treated as a string, not dict.

Comment: @MateuszM. thanks for pointing out. It was copy pasted from OP's code snippet and I forgot removing.

Comment: {{form.fullName(class='form-control', value={{x}}, placeholder="FirstName LastName")  }}
how to add the x value for flask wtf form that come from server